# How to access an enviroment variable of `$SUDO_USER`'s within a shell script?

Tags: shell-script, sudo, environment-variables

- My `$USER`'s `$SHELL` env variable is `/bin/zsh`
- My root's `$SHELL` env variable is `/bin/bash`

I am running a Unix shell script as `sudo`. In this script, I need to check if `$SHELL` env variable of  `$SUDO_USER` is `/bin/zsh`. However, in this command:

```bash
if [ $SHELL != "/bin/zsh" ]; then
  pacman -S --needed --no-confirm zsh
  sudo -u $SUDO_USER chsh -s /usr/bin/zsh
fi
```

`$SHELL` is actually the root's env viable. How to get `$SHELL` of `$SUDO_USER`'s instead?

Thank you.

**edit**
It is preferable an approach that could be other environment variable besides the `$SHELL` variable.

Comment: I'm not sure what are you trying to do here. Change the shell from the user running the script or change the root user shell?

Comment: I am confused either, what is the problem actually? Can not get $SUDO_USER?

Comment: @Parker I am trying to access the `$SHELL` env variable of user `$USER`, but in a unix shell script that as ran as sudo. Simple like that.

Comment: @HansChen I do not wat `$SUDO_USER`, I want `$SHELL` of `$SUDO_USER`

Comment: @RubemPacelli Would running with sudo -E an option? For example `sudo -E ./test.sh`

Comment: @HansChen Yes! That's great! I didn't know that it is possible, thank you!

Comment: In this case I put this into answer, might be helpful for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use option `-E, --preserve-env` with `sudo` to carry the environment.
For example `sudo -E ./test.sh`.

Please note to allow any environment is not encouraged. Please refer to **Command environment** section in `man sudoers`.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, the `$SHELL` environment variable is set according to the 7th field of the user's `/etc/passwd` entry, so if you are looking for `$SUDO_USER`'s *default* shell, you could look it up directly from there:

```
if [ $(getent passwd $SUDO_USER | cut -d: -f 7) != "/bin/zsh" ]; then
  ...
```

But if you want the value of the exact shell the `sudo` command was issued from, you need to look at the environment of the grandparent process:

```
get_ppid() {
  ps -ho ppid -p "$1" | tr -d " "
}

SUDO_USERS_SHELLPID=$(get_ppid $( get_ppid $$ ))  # get the PID of this shell's grandparent

# if you want the actual pathname of the shell used as the grandparent process:
if [ $(readlink /proc/$SUDO_USERS_SHELLPID/exe) != "/bin/zsh" ]; then
  ...

# or if you want the $SHELL environment value from the grandparent process:
if [ $(strings /proc/$SUDO_USERS_SHELLPID/environ | awk -F= '/^SHELL=/{ print $2; }') != "/bin/zsh" ]; then
  ...
```